psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en «127.0.0.1», puerto 5432: FATAL: no existe la base de datos «ordersdb»
Hola! Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos postgres

Cuando hago el test me sale: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos �ordersdb�

y lo mismo al internar conectarme desde el cmd

C:\Users\usuario>psql -U postgres -d ordersdb -h 127.0.0.1
Contraseña para usuario postgres:
psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en
«127.0.0.1», puerto 5432: FATAL:  no existe la base de datos «ordersdb»

Mi docker compose:
version: '3'

services:
  orders-bd:
    container_name: orders_database
    image: postgres:16.2 
    restart: always 
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123456
      - POSTGRES_DB=ordersdb

Lista de bases de datos:

¿Por qué puede ser? ¿Algo estoy haciendo mal?
Laptop
Windows 10
psql (PostgreSQL) 16.1
Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b

¿Has intentado conectarte a otra base de datos?

prueba usando la base de datos postgres, y luego de eso lista la bases que tienes en el servidor

Ya me dieron la solución! Muchas gracias.
Esta solución me dieron:

El error puede ser debido a que ya tienes
PostgreSQL instalado o que algún otro programa está usando el puerto
5432 de tu computador. Trata de colocar lo siguiente en tu archivo de
Docker Compose.

> ports:
>     - 5433:5432


De esta manera, nos estaremos asegurando de que estás usando un puerto
desocupado de tu computador, luego elimina la carpeta de postgres que
se creó en el proyecto junto al contenedor de Docker y después vuelve
a ejecutar nuevamente el comando de docker compose up -d. Esto debería
solucionar el problema, después, a la hora de conectarte a la interfaz
de base de datos, debes de colocar el puerto 5433 en vez del 5432.

